# MongoDB: multiple $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have MongoDB documents structured like this:

```
{_id: ObjectId("53d760721423030c7e14266f"),
fruit: 'apple',
vitamins: [
    {
     _id: 1,
     name: 'B7',
     usefulness: 'useful',
     state: 'free',
    }
    {
     _id: 2,
     name: 'A1',
     usefulness: 'useful',
     state: 'free',
    }
    {
     _id: 3,
     name: 'A1',
     usefulness: 'useful',
     state: 'non_free',
    }
  ]
}
{_id: ObjectId("53d760721423030c7e142670"),
fruit: 'grape',
vitamins: [
    {
     _id: 4,
     name: 'B6',
     usefulness: 'useful',
     state: 'free',
    }
    {
     _id: 5,
     name: 'A1',
     usefulness: 'useful',
     state: 'non_free',
    }
    {
     _id: 6,
     name: 'Q5',
     usefulness: 'non_useful',
     state: 'non_free',
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to query and get all the fruits which have both `{name: 'A1', state: 'non_free'}` and `{name: 'B7', state: 'free'}`.
In the worst case I want at least to count these entries if getting them is not possible and  if the equivalent code exists for pymongo, to know how to write it.

For the given example I want to retrieve only the apple (first) document.

If I use `$elemMatch` it works only for one condition, but not for both. E.g. if I query `find({'vitamins': {'$elemMatch': {'name': 'A1', 'state': 'non_free'}, '$elemMatch': {'name': 'B7', 'state': 'free'}}})` it will retrieve all the fruits with `{'name': 'B7', 'state': 'free'}`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In this case you can use the [`$and`-operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) .

Try this query:

```
find({
    $and: [
         {'vitamins': {'$elemMatch': {'name': 'A1', 'state': 'non_free'} } },
         {'vitamins': {'$elemMatch': {'name': 'B7', 'state': 'free'} } }
    ]
});
```

To explain why you received only the result matching the second criteria: The objects inside each `{}` you pass to MongoDB are key/value pairs. Each key can only exist once per object. When you try to assign a value to the same key twice, the second assignment will override the first. In your case you assigned two different values to the key `$elemMatch` in the same object, so the first one was ignored. The query which actually arrived in MongoDB was just `find({'vitamins': {'$elemMatch': {'name': 'B7', 'state': 'free'}}})`.

Whenever you need to apply the same operator to the same key twice, you need to use `$or` or `$and`.

Comment: but I need the fruit to have **both** the vitamins and not either of them

Comment: @gevra My bad, In that case use `$and` instead of `$or`. Updated answer.

Comment: use `$and` instead `$or`

Comment: @Philipp you are so quickly :)

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this dynamically for an unknown number of $elemMatch's ?

Comment: @chillinpuma You could build the array you pass to `$and` dynamically on the application.

Answer (score 8):

```
var fruits = db.fruits.find({
    "vitamins": {
        $all: [{
            $elemMatch: {
                "name": "A1",
                "state": "non_free"
            }
        }, {
            $elemMatch: {
                "name": "B7",
                "state": "free"
            }
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: please explaint your answer

Comment: The Query finds the documents which satisfy the below conditions
1) Exact sub document match for name :B7 and state : free
2) Exact sub document match for name :A1 and state : non_free
and the array should satisy both the conditions for that i used $all operator

Comment: As per stackoverflow, you should explain the answer

Comment: Note: "The $all is equivalent to an $and operation of the specified values" from [$all operator docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#equivalent-to-and-operation)

Answer (score -2):

```
let query = [];
  query.push({
    id: product.id,
  });
  query.push({ date });
  for (const slot of slots) {
    query.push({
      slots: {
        $elemMatch: {
          id: slot.id,
          spots: { $gte: slot.spots },
        },
      },
    });
  }
  const cal = await Product.findOne({ $and: query });
```

Comment: This does not seems like native mongo query or python code as tagged by the question.